# Visual Studio 作成したアプリでの『アセンブリ署名』について

Tags: visual-studio

お世話になります。

VisualStudio2019、C#で社内向けのアプリケーションを作りました。
InstallerProjectを使用してインストーラーまで作ることができたのですが、
セキュリティ対策などの『アセンブリ署名』というものがどんなものなのか解りません。

どうやって行うのか、何のために行うのか、行った結果、どういうことができるのかを教えてください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### [アセンブリに厳格な名前を付ける理由](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/assembly/strong-named#why-strong-name-your-assemblies)
>
> 厳密な名前付きのアセンブリを参照すると、バージョン管理や名前の一意性を保護できるなどの利点を期待できます。 .NET Framework では、厳密な名前付きのアセンブリは、一部のシナリオを有効にするために必要な、グローバル アセンブリ キャッシュにインストールできます。

というわけで同名のアセンブリが存在したとしても、自分が作成したアセンブリを特定できるようにするための機構です。

同ページには

> 警告
>   セキュリティに関しては、厳格な名前に依存しないでください。 厳格な名前は、一意の ID を提供するだけです。

ともあり、セキュリティ対策とは無関係です。

Comment: ありがとうございました。いつも助けていただいてすみません。また、先日は何度も質問を書き換えてしまい、本当にすみませんでした。回答の件、ありがとうございました。やっとわかった気がしました。これからもよろしくお願いいたします。